# SFML Error (Code block) : The procedure entry point could not be located in graphics, window,system library

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks, sfml, dynamic-linking

I just installed SFML , and I followed the instruction for using SFML with codeblock
[HERE](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/start-cb.php)

I got the following error[image]:

> The procedure entry point ... could not be located in dynamic link
> library for graphics, then(after I click ok) window, then(after I
> click ok) system.

- I have copied all dll files to the same path as my executable
- I have read other questions regarding linking problem , I noticed that one said that this problem is due to **different version of dll**(I'm not sure, I'm a total beginner) ,and the solution to that is the dll files of SFML should be compiled by ourself. HOWEVER, the post did not mention how to do so.

Is that ^ really the cause of the problem? Please explain.

If so, **PLEASE give the DETAIL steps how to compile the dll files of SFML** and any further steps needed afterward,

If no, please explain what is the problem and suggest a detail solution for the problem.

Thanks

Comment: What are the libraries you link to?

Comment: @AndreasDM I downloaded SFML 2.4.0 for Windows : GCC 6.1.0 MINGW(DW2) - 32 bit from this download page http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.4.0/

Comment: In the *linker settings*, do you link to the libraries: *sfml-graphics*, *sfml-window* and *sfml-system* in that order? Did you define  *SFML-STATIC* or not?

Comment: @AndreasDM Yes I put sfml-graphics, window, and system in that order just like the in the instruction page. No, I did not define static, but I copied all dll to the same path as my executable

Comment: The files are named `libsfml-graphics.a` etc., did you put them in the working directory?

Comment: @AndreasDM Yes, I have tried copying all the .a files including libsfml-graphics to the same path as my executable! It didn't work

Comment: You then need to specify where to find the libraries in codeblocks, in the compiler and linker settings

Comment: @AndreasDM I have done so as the instruction page said. I specify the include file location , and the lib file location..... Is tht what you meant?